# modify umask of a running process

Tags: bash, python, umask

I have a program, which can be used by a group and thus the output should have group writing permission by default, thus `umask 002`. Of course each user could do `(umask 002 && cmd)`.
But since this is cumbersome and error prone, I want to set it umask within the cmd. How can this be done?
cmd has the possibility to spawn shell command.

It seems to be possible, as there is a built-in solution in python
(see code #1 in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-umask-method).
Well, I have another language; but knowing how it is done in `os` of python might help (I'm stucked here https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.3/Modules/posixmodule.c#l2677).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell the programming language you want to use. There is a system call `umask` which is called in the linked C file.

Comment: @Bodo The language in cmd is idl, but is also allows to call c function (https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/basiccexamples.html). If cmd would be a bash script, then it seems one could just use `bash <<<"umask 0002; echo 'hello' > foo; ls -gG foo"`.

Comment: **Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification to the question**, instead of using comments for this purpose. You should add clarification for IDL. To my knowledge, "interface definition language" is more known than "interactive data language". So is there any remaining question? There is a function `umask`, and you can call C functions from IDL.

Answer (score 2):

Do that `(umask 002 && cmd)` for them.

Make a script that sets the umask, and only then starts the actual program. Then, put the wrapper script somewhere in `PATH` before the actual command, or rename the program itself and put the wrapper script in its place. (Make sure to call the renamed program from the script, though.)

E.g. if the program is `/usr/bin/foo`, and you have `/usr/local/bin` first in PATH, create `/usr/local/bin/foo` that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
umask 002 &&
exec /usr/bin/foo "$@"
```

(the `"$@"` passes any and all command line arguments to the program itself.)

Or rename `/usr/bin/foo` to `/usr/bin/foo.orig`, install the script as `/usr/bin/foo` and have it run `/usr/bin/foo.orig`.

Of course you could modify the program itself, but using a wrapper works regardless of how the program was implemented. Renaming and replacing the script can be an issue with upgrades though, as the new version might clobber your script, so using another directory may be better in that. (Though there's things like `dpkg-divert` on Debian that can be used to tell the package manager to put the file somewhere else.)

---

Note that this is easy since we're just starting the program in question. Forcing a change to the umask of an *already running* process from the outside would be a whole another issue, and impossible with standard tools.

<sub>(On Linux, you could attach to the program with `gdb`, and make it do the `umask()` system call without the actual program knowing. But that's hacky and only works if debugging isn't restricted with `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope`. It probably is in modern systems.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

So cmd has to call `umask` (from "libc.so.6").

Examples:

- bash: If cmd is a bash script, it could be just moved inside the cmd script:

```bsh
umask 2
```

- Python: The built-in `os.umask` can be used:

```py
import os
oct(os.umask(0o0002))
```

- Python: Reimplementation to demonstrate the c-library call (unix)

```py
from ctypes import CDLL
libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
libc.umask(2)
```

- idl:

```
print, call_external('libc.so.6', 'umask', '0002'O, /all_value, /auto_glue), format='(O)'
```

where `O` indicates octal format.

```
print, call_external('libc.so.6', 'umask', 0, 0), format='(O)'
```

That works, but it behaves strange in idl, which is another story. (One would expect `call_external('libc.so.6', 'umask', 2, /value)` would be required. The number passed to umask seems to be the number of args. And when umask was originally 0022, the first call returns 18!?).

Comment: re. `0022` vs. `18`, the C convention is that numbers starting with zeroes are _octal_, so `022` is 2*8+2 = 18 in decimal. People don't use octal much these days, but it is used for permission bits since the digits line up nicely with the three-bit rwx groups. (The shell's `umask` command always takes the argument in octal, but you'd need e.g. `umask(022)` in C and `os.umask(0o022)` in Python to get that umask. Doesn't matter for ones that look like `00x`, of course.)

Comment: I don't know anything about idl, but you may want to check that that `call_external('libc.so.6', 'umask', 0, 0)` doesn't set the umask to just zero, giving write permission to everyone.

Comment: @ilkkachu "octal" very good hint! Python also has the `oct` function. And in idl `print, '22'O`.

Comment: with printf formats, it's `%o` to print in octal, so e.g. `printf("0%o\n", 18)` in C or `18 % "0%o"` in Python to get `022`.